# StatusBar ignores `.lightContent` style only in iOS 15

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, uikit

I have a complex project using `ViewController based status bar appearance = YES`, `Status bar style = Light Content`, dynamic changes on status bar style, etc. Everything works fine in iOS 14, but in iOS 15 the status bar is always black.

Can anyone point any help?

Answer (score 0):

Try do this:

`override var preferredStatusBarStyle : UIStatusBarStyle { return .lightContent }`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).